# Angular.js ng-show не обновляется в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, angularjs

У при нажатии на кнопку появляться модальное окно

```
<div id="info-top-modal" class="custom-modal" ng-controller="userController">
        <div class="custom-modal-content" ng-init="showTabOne=true; showTabTwo=false;">
            <div class="user-loader" ng-show="isLoad">
                <div class="spinner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 tab-change">
                <button ng-class="{'selected-modal-btn': showTabOne}" 
                        ng-click="showTabOne = true; showTabTwo = false;">Вход</button>
                <button ng-class="{'selected-modal-btn': showTabTwo}"
                        ng-click="showTabTwo = true; showTabOne = false;">Регистрация</button>
                <button class="fa fa-times close-modal" ng-click="closeUserModal();"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 modal-tab selected-modal-tab" ng-show="showTabOne">
                <div class="col-md-12 user-modal-input" ng-class="{ 'errorlogin': userNotFound }">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="oldUserLogin"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 user-modal-input">
                    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                    <input type="password" ng-model="oldUserPassword"/>
                </div>
                <button ng-disabled="oldUserLogin.length < 6" ng-click="Login();">Вход</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 modal-tab" ng-show="showTabTwo">
                    <div class="col-md-12 user-modal-input">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="newUserLogin"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 user-modal-input">
                        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                        <input type="password" ng-model="newUserPassword"/>
                    </div>
                    <button ng-click="Create();">Регистрация</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

при после ввода данных при нажатии на кнопку выполнятся метод из контролера

```
$scope.Login = async function(){
        $scope.isLoad = true;
        let user = await httpQuery.getUser($scope.oldUserLogin, $scope.oldUserPassword);
        if(user.NotFound){
            console.log('data error');
            $scope.isLoad = false;
        }
        // userData.setUser(user);
        // $scope.closeUserModal();
    }
```

я показываю анимацию ожидания ответа

```
<div class="user-loader" ng-show="isLoad">
                <div class="spinner"></div>
            </div>
```

Анимация появляться но не пропадает хотя в консоли выводит сообщение что ответ получен.

Comment: У вас `$scope.isLoad = false` работает только тогда, когда `user.NotFound`, если пользователь будет найден, то `isLoad` останется `true`. Так задумано?

Comment: на тот что писал да так нада было уже

Comment: Возможно, ваш лоадер в другом контроллере работает.